# Quantum confinement effect of phonons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, crystals, vibrations, phonons

I wonder what length scale is necessary to observe quantum confinement effects of phonons. I am supposing the situation of quantum wells (two dimensional). In case of electrons, by knowing Bohr radius, one can roughly evaluate the length scale necessary to observe the confinement effect. How about phonons? Is there a similar concept that corresponds to Bohr radius in electron? Specifically, I am supposing the phonon frequncy/dispersion change induced by the quantum confinement effect.

Comment: Phonon wavelength seems as the obvious candidate. In fact, I believe there was research activity on the subject... perhaps already a decade ago.

Comment: I found one book telling about this topic. It seems very thin well/barrier layer thicknesses are necessary to observe this effect in phonons, i.e., several monolayers. The description on repetition is lacked. So, it is necessary to look for.